# Yii urlManager parameter

Tags: yii

I am trying to use the following url: (With the htaccess applied)

/user/{username}

to redirect to something like:

/user/view/{username}

I have no clue what the rule should be...

My current urlManager config is:

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,       
        'rules'=>array(
        )
    ),
```

I'm also going to want some overrides such as (That go to the regular action)

/user/settings

/user/edit

etc... how would I add these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own!

```
'user/settings' => 'user/settings',
'user/<action>/*' => 'user/view/user/<action>',
```

Comment: Delete the first one . . . it'll just slow you down as rules process in order, and it's not doing anything.

Comment: Incorrect, actually. The top one stops the next ones from being used, allowing me to have more than JUST user redirects. It's absolutely necessary for what I need

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the first was a subset of your second rule.  My mistake.